# Relation of the sample size to the sample mean

Tags: probability

Problem:
$X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables, each with expected value 75 and standard deviation 15.
a) How many <s>samples</s>observations in a sample, $n$, do we need to guarantee that the sample mean, $M_n(X)$, is between 74 and 76 with probability 0.99?
b) If each $X_i$ has a Gaussian distribution, how many <s>samples</s>observations in a sample, $n'$, do we need to guarantee that the sample mean, $M_{n'}(X)$, is between 74 and 76 with probability 0.99?

Attempt at Solution:
I know that the equation for the sample mean is $M_n(X) = \frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n}{n}$. I also know that the Chebyshev inequality states that $P(|X-\mu|\geq c) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{c^2}$. However, I am not sure how to combine these two in order to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard deviation of a sample mean (aka standard error SE) is:
$$\sigma_{M_n(X)} = SE = \frac \sigma {\sqrt n}$$
Therefore:
$$P(|M_n(X)-\mu|\ge c) \le \frac{SE^2}{c^2}$$

Since you want $M_n(X)$ to be between $74$ and $76$ with $0.99$ probability, that means that the probability that the sample mean deviates more than $1$ from its mean is less than $0.01$:
$$P(|M_n(X)-75|\ge 1) \le 0.01$$
To guarantee that, we need:
$$\frac{SE^2}{1^2} \le 0.01$$
$$\frac{\sigma^2}{n} \le 0.01$$
$$n \ge \frac{\sigma^2}{0.01} = \frac{15^2}{0.01} = 22500$$